# Many-to-many fluent NHibernate issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with many to many mapping with fluent in a mvc4 application,
when database (SQL2012Express) is create, the two tables to map aren't created.

I want to map in to many to many relation, because a product can be associated to many category and category can be many product. In my class Category I have :

```
public class Categoria : BaseEntity
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Prodotti> Prodotti { get; set; }

    public Categoria()
    {
        Prodotti = new List<Prodotti>();
    }

    public virtual void AddProdotti(Prodotti pro)
    {
        Prodotti.Add(pro);
    }
}
```

And in prduct class:

```
public class Prodotti:BaseEntity
{

  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }

  public virtual void AddCategorie(Categoria cat)
    {
        Categoria.Add(cat);
    }

  public Prodotti()
    {
        Categoria = new List<Categoria>();
    }

}
```

The class map respectively are:

```
public class CategoriaMap : ClassMap<Categoria>
{

    public CategoriaMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("Id");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Active).Default("True");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Prodotti)
            .Inverse()
            .Table("CategoryProductsMap")
            .ParentKeyColumn("CategoriaId").ChildKeyColumn("ProdottiId")
            .Cascade.All(); ;
    }
}

public class ProdottiMap :ClassMap<Prodotti>
{
     public ProdottiMap()
     { 
         Id(x=>x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("Id");
         Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
         Map(x => x.Price).Precision(3);
         Map(x => x.isFeatured).Nullable();
         Map(x => x.ShortDescription);
         Map(x => x.FullDescription);
         Map(x => x.ShowOnHomePage).Nullable();
         Map(x => x.Images);
         Map(x => x.Published).Default("False");
         Map(x => x.MetaDescription);
         Map(x => x.MetaKeywords);
         Map(x => x.MetaTitle);
         Map(x => x.SeName);
         Map(x => x.Deleted).Default("False");
         Map(x => x.MinimumPurchaseCount);

         Map(x => x.ShippingWeight);
         Map(x => x.ShippingHeight);
         Map(x => x.ShippingLength);
         Map(x => x.ShippingWidth);

         Map(x => x.CreatedOnUtc);
         Map(x => x.UpdatedOnUtc);

         HasManyToMany(x => x.Categoria)                 
            .Table("CategoryProductsMap")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProdottiId").ChildKeyColumn("CategoriaId"); 
     }
}
```

The configuration is:

```
var configuration =Fluently.Configure()
               .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ShowSql().ConnectionString(c =>
               c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Connection1")))
               .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<latticinibufala.Entities.Maps.CustomerMap>()        )
                // Set session context class to enable ManagedWebSessionContext usage
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "managed_web"))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "10"))
                .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                .BuildConfiguration()
                ;

            sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: In what way does it not work? How does your CategoryMap look?

Comment: not work because in the database table appear only "CategoryProductsMap" but not Category and Product.
Can you explain when write how does your CategoryMap?
Perhaps you want to know how i have mapped category, excuse me but don't understand the question!

Comment: Can you check if setting columns to "Prodotti_Id" and to "Categoria_Id" will fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to your `CategoriaMap` constructor

```
Table("Categoria");
```

and following to `ProdottiMap` constructor

```
Table("Prodotti");
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply,i have tried but still doesn't create the tables

Answer (score 0):

i have solved, the wrong line code is: 
    Map(x => x.Active).Default("True");

because the database want a number 1 = True

Answer (score 0):

Just Add to you fuent-nHibernate configuration file

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
props.Add("query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
```

and then

```
.BuildConfiguration().AddProperties(props);
```